# AWS, ELB, EC2 - How to enable detailed request logging for EC2 instances using ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

ASP.NET MVC and WebApi application being deployed using the Visual Studio deployment tools via the AWS SDK.

I want to enable detailed request logging on IIS on all instances when deployed under ELB.

I think this is in the file "systeminfo.xml" and in this node.

However, I don't know where this file live, nor how to impact change on it when deploying.

Is there a setting somewhere in the AWS console that will make this change and new deployments will honor it?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the AWS Console, you can only control logging for ELB. You can
   enable detailed ELB logging and configure an S3 bucket for what goes
   in and goes out.
2. Any logging within an EC2 instance must be configured from within
   the instance. I know little about IIS and cannot comment on it's
   configuration. But based on your question, you need to find where
   the systeminfo.xml resides in the IIS installation, configure it to
   enable logging.
3. You can further enhance your implementation by deploying an [AWS
   CloudWatch Logs agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) to publish your logs to AWS Cloud Watch.

Comment: RE #3 - this would only push the ELB logs though, correct?